# Char array manipulatiion

Tags: c, arrays, char

So I'm learning C slowly but surely and I'm confused on these outputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {

      mycat(5);
      mycat(7);
      mycat(30);

      return 0; // from everything I've read this is necessary...?

}

char dest_buffer[100];
char str1[] = "Hello";
char str2[] = "World";

void mycat(int n) {

    strcat(str1, str2);
    memcpy(dest_buffer, str1, n);
    printf("%s\n", dest_buffer);

}
```

These are the outputs I get.

```
>Hello
>HelloWo
>HelloWorldorldorldorld
```

The last one, according to directions, should just return HelloWorld. I'm not entirely sure why it just keeps saying "orld" times after it. Any help to assist in correcting this would be great! I'm not too sure what to do here.

Comment: You're accessing non-allocated memory so it is UB and it's going to vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: For example, with `gcc` and `clang`, I get an aborted call. Not all compilers will do this though.

Comment: If someone did answer your question to your satisfaction, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer so others know what solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

To get a better understanding of what is happening, change the length of your `str1` and `str2` arrays to a length of 100, just so we don't get weird, undefined behavior.

@Eli Sadoff is absolutely correct; when you define a string like `char str1[] = "Hello"`, then that allocated chunk of memory is only 6 bytes in size: 5 characters plus a `NULL` terminator. When you concatenate strings with `strcat`, you must ensure your destination has enough memory. Here is a useful resource for FreeBSD's implementation of `strcat` that you may find helpful: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strcat&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.3-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html

Let's also print `str1` and label our `printf` statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char dest_buffer[100];
char str1[100] = "Hello";                  // changed to 100
char str2[100] = "World";                  // changed to 100

void mycat(int n) {
    strcat(str1, str2);
    printf("str1 =   %s\n, str1);          // added so you can see str1
    memcpy(dest_buffer, str1, n);
    printf("buffer = %s\n", dest_buffer);  // labeled buffer printout
}

int main() {
    mycat(5);
    mycat(7);
    mycat(30);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
str1   = HelloWorld
buffer = Hello
str1   = HelloWorldWorld
buffer = HelloWo
str1   = HelloWorldWorldWorld
buffer = HelloWorldWorldWorld
```

To your question: why does the last string say `World` 3 times? It is because each time you call `mycat`, you are calling the method `strcat(str1, str2)`, which puts `str2` and a `/0` terminator on the end of `str1` starting from the first `/0` in str1.

So you see, `str1` gets another copy of `str2` appended every time you call `mycat` and then you do `memcpy` on only `n` bytes, and always starting the the beginning of the buffer. That is why when you print the `buffer` it is sometimes truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Two things may help to understand why the program is behaving in this way.  First, understand that char strings in C are typically terminated by a null byte, so to start, "Hello" is actually 6 bytes.  Second, statically allocated variables are stored on the stack in contiguous memory, so you can think of str1 and str2 as taking up 12 consecutive bytes.

In your function, you call strcat, which copies bytes from str2 onto str1, starting at the null byte.  After the first call, those 12 bytes look like "HelloWorld\0\0", because you copied over the null byte in the first string, and strcat null terminated its output.  Str2 still points to the 7th byte of those 12, which is "orld\0\0".  The next call to strcat will append "orld" to the string, giving you "HelloWorldorld\0".  At this point str2 points to  "orldorld\0", and the third call to strcat will append those bytes.

So, when you call memcpy to copy n bytes, you get the mucked up string pointed to by str1.  An important point here: you statically allocated 6 bytes to str2, and your code has walked off the allocated space into memory probably being used by something else in the stack.  This is a very bad thing, and bound for a segfault.